# Insert missing data only in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, the first table has 400 rows. The second table holds the same records with the same count. Now the first table row count increases to 450. I want to insert only those 50 new rows into the second table. I don't need to update the first 400 records.

I am setting the unique index for the particular field (like empid). Now when I insert the first table data it returns the following error:

```
Duplicate entry 'xxxx' for key 'idx_confirm'
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Am using the below code to insert the record. But it allows duplicate entry..

```
insert ignore into tbl_emp_confirmation (fldemp_id,fldempname,fldjoindatefldstatus)
select fldempid, fldempname,DATE_FORMAT (fldjoindate,'%Y-%m-%d') as fldjoindate,fldstatus from tblempgeneral as n;
```

Comment: You are violating a key constraint on the table you are inserting into.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `INSERT ...` statement to `INSERT IGNORE ...`.

See for example [this post](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-ignore/) for an explanation.

You need to make sure that you have a unique index that prevents any duplicates, such as on the primary key.

Comment: No, sorry, I lost my sample code. Check out the link I added.